# Maximin diameter of a transformed convex figure

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, affine-geometry

You are given a compact convex figure in the plane, $C$.

Your goal is to transform $C$ to a different figure $C'$ with the smallest possible diameter, as long as:

- The trasformation from $C$ to $C'$ is [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) and invertible (e.g. scaling in one or more directions);
- $C'$ contains a disc with diameter $1$.

For example:

- If $C$ is an ellipse, you can transform it to a disc with diameter $1$.
- If $C$ is a parallelogram, you can transform it to a square with side-length $1$ and diameter $\sqrt{2}$.
- If $C$ is a triangle, you can transform it to an equilateral triangle with diameter $\sqrt{3}$.

An ellipse is obviously the best case; what is the worst case?

<sup>Cross-post from [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161169/29780)</sup>

Comment: What you are trying to do (at least in the centrally symmetric case) is to compute the Banach-Mazur distance between (the equivalence class of) C and (the equivalence class of) a round disk. Google "Banach-Mazur" and "John ellipsoid" and you will find relevant information.

Comment: @JairoBochi thanks! This Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_distance mentions an upper bound of $n$ (the number of dimensions, here 2) on the Banach-Mazur distance, which seems reasonable. But, I am not sure how this distance relates to the diameter. Also, I do not know what is the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Second version after incomplete first version, using [John's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid) and some remarks thereon by Keith Ball.

==

The worst case is the triangle (as intuition predicts). A few images would be really helpful, but at the moment I don't have time for this, so let me just indicate the main arguments.

To see why the triangle is the worst case, we consider a compact convex $C$, with boundary $\delta C$.

By [John's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid) we know that $C$ contains a maximal-area (inscribed) ellipse $E_C$. W.l.o.g. the center of $E_C$ is the origin $(0,0)$ (otherwise translate). Our first affine transformation (say $G$) is to downscale $C$ in the longitudinal direction of the semi-major axis of $E_C$, with factor $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b$ are the lengths of the semi-minor and semi-major axis of $E_C$ respectively.

We then have that $G(E_C)$ is a circle, say $M$. $M$ is the maximal-area inscribed ellipse of our transformed compactum $G(C)$. Our second affine transformation $H$ is a global scaling with a factor $\frac{1}{r}$ where $r$ is the radius of $M$.

Then $H\circ G (C)=C'$ has $H(M)$ as maximal-area inscribed ellipse, and $H(M)=M'$ is the unit circle with radius $1$.

Now we apply ([Keith Ball's comments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201217.pdf) on) John's theorem, to find $m$ real numbers $c_i>0$ (for $1\leq i\leq m$) and corresponding intersection points $u_i$ of $M'$ with $\delta C'$, the boundary of $C'$, such that:

a) $\Sigma c_i\cdot u_i=0$

b) $\Sigma c_i\cdot \langle x,u_i\rangle\cdot u_i=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$

John's theorem actually states that the unit circle (which is $M'$) is the maximal-area inscribed ellipse of a convex $K$ **if and only if** $K$ has intersection points $u_i$ with the unit circle admitting real numbers $c_i>0$ such that criteria a) and b) hold.

In Keith Ball's words: Condition a) shows that the contact points do not all lie "on one side" of the unit circle, and condition b) that they do not all lie "close to a proper subspace". In other words, they are sufficiently spread out over the unit circle.

$C'$ is contained entirely within the polygon $P$ delineated by the $m$ tangent lines $l_i$ to the unit circle $M'$ in the points $u_i$ respectively (picture!). The trivial reason for this is that $C$ is convex.

The polygon $P$ also has the unit circle as maximal-area inscribed ellipse, once again by John's theorem since a) and b) also hold for $P$.

In [Keith Ball's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201217.pdf) it is proved that any convex $K$ for which the unit circle is the maximal-area inscribed ellipse, is contained in the disc around the origin with radius $2$ ($2\cdot B_2$, globally scaled twice the unit disc).

Therefore $P$ is contained in $2\cdot B_2$. From this it follows that the triangle is the worst case, using conditions a) and b). This is elegantly proved in the final remark on page 11,12 of [Keith Ball's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201217.pdf), stating for dimension $n$:

If $C$ is a convex body with the Euclidean unit ball $B_n$ as maximal-volume ellipsoid, then diam$(C)\leq\sqrt{2n(n+1)}$.

Comment: Actually, this second  version is nothing new from what Keith Ball already observed, so ... the first commenter JairoBochi was right I believe. Still, I hope to  have clarified his remark now. Perhaps this version can elicit some comments, I'm quite occupied with other things but will check for reactions.

Comment: ($\star$) still needs a precise proof, but one "sees" that a polygon $P$ with angle smaller than $\frac{\pi}{3}$  is oblong, and therefore does not have a circle as maximal-area inscribed ellipse. [btw I removed my previous comments on the incorrect first version since no-one reacted anyway :-)]

Comment: Completed the details of $(\star)$, they were also to be found already in Keith Ball's paper but it took me some time to realize this.

Comment: I tried several intuitive high-school level shortcuts, but discovered a glaring incompleteness in each one. And this after having described them already as answer... Not good for my self-esteem, but so be it. Anyway, it does leave me with the feeling that for $\mathbb{R}^2$ a high-school level answer is possible (without too much coordinate calculus I mean). Also I would like to know whether for polygon P with maximal-area inscribed ellipse $S_1$ and all angles > $\frac{\pi}{3}$, diam$(P)$ is less than $2\sqrt{3}$ (as I strongly suspect).